# How do I make a certain javascript function execute on page load for all its elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function defined as follows (note that it does not use jquery):

```
function getCalculationFormsByType(selectObject, parentNode, countIndex)
{
    var operationID = parseInt(selectObject.value, 10);

    var divs = parentNode.getElementsByTagName("DIV");

    // the rest of the function goes here, it isn't really important ...
}
```

The function is executed in the following way (again, no jquery):

```
<select name="operationChoose[]" onchange="getCalculationFormsByType(this, this.parentNode.parentNode, '1')" >
```

Everything works so far. The problem is that I need to execute this function on page load for all `select` elements on the page. Like this (my idea uses jquery, but it isn't necessary for the solution):

```
$("document").ready(function(){
   $("select[name='operationChoose[]']").each(function(){
      getCalculationFormsByType(---I DO NOT KNOW WHAT TO PASS HERE---);
   });
});
```

As you can see, my problem is that I don't know what to pass into the function in jQuery. I don't know what those 3 values in javascript are and how can I get them in jQuery's `each` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be able to access javascipt's `parentNode`, so just transfer jQuery object to classic javascript one.

Additionaly, "document" will never work. Use `document` or shorthand

```
$(function(){
   $("select[name='operationChoose[]']").each(function(){
      getCalculationFormsByType(this, this.parentNode.parentNode, '1');
   });
});
```

Comment: @Rob W My bad. Corrected in my second argument. It is correct now

Comment: it's better to drop `$(this)[0]` completely, and use `this` instead. Your current method is equal to building a cage around a dog, then opening the door to let the dog out, to touch him. Not necessary, and expensive.

Comment: @Rob W I stop it just after I posted my answer, but then yours appeared. If I change it now, it will be just duplicate of your answer/your answer will be duplicated of mine. But, like you said, it's a bad method. Edited anyways

Answer (score 2):

The quotes in `$("document").ready` should be removed. Also, `$(..function here..)` is a shorthand for `$(document).ready(...)`.

This is the correct implementation:

```
$(function() {
   $("select[name='operationChoose[]']").each(function(i) {  // <-- i-th element
      // this points to the <select> element, HTMLSelectElement
      getCalculationFormsByType(this, this.parentNode.parentNode, i);
   });
});
```